# django url with or condition

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I have an app in django - 1.11. When changing the language in the template, the address appears: `localhost:8000/en/events/None/None/None`

Below solution is OK.

My question is it possible to join these 4 regexes with one regex? For example, add something like `or` into regex?

My dirty solution with few url regex:

```
url(r'^$', views.ListView.as_view(), name='list'),
url(r'^(?:/(?P<filter1>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?$', views.ListView.as_view(), name='list'),
url(r'^(?:/(?P<filter1>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?(?:/(?P<filter2>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?$', views.ListView.as_view(), name='list'),
url(r'^(?:/(?P<filter1>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?(?:/(?P<filter2>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?(?:/(?P<filter3>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?$', views.ListView.as_view(), name='list'),
```

Comment: It seems you only need forth regex. It will match other three as well.

Comment: with the last one I got `localhost:8000/en/events/None/None/None` after changed language

Comment: What should you get then? and which part should it match?

Comment: You can chain the patterns with alternations `|` if this is helpful.